# Traversing a JSON file from the inner nodes out c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file that contains a nested structure.  The levels are:

- Top Level
- Mid Level
- Bottom level

So for every top level object there may be 1 or more children and for the mid level there may be one or more children.  Here is a sample of the JSON file:

```
 "Description": {
  "ProductCategoryID": "12345",
  "Title": "Tables",
  "Description": "Tables",
  "LanguageId": 57
},
"Display": {
  "ProductCategoryId": "12345",
  "ShowWeb": true,
  "ShowMobile": true,
  "ShowDatavault": true
},
"Image": null,
"Children": [
  {
    "Description": {
      "ProductCategoryDescriptionId": "abc123",
      "ProductCategoryId": "ABCDE",
      "Title": "Rectangular",
      "Description": "Rectangular",
      "LanguageId": 57
    },
    "Display": {
      "ProductCategoryId": "xxxxxxx",
      "ShowWeb": true,
      "ShowMobile": true,
      "ShowDatavault": true
    },
    "Image": null,
    "Children": [
      {
        "Description": {
          "ProductCategoryDescriptionId": "xxx",
          "ProductCategoryId": "xxxxx",
          "Title": "8-Foot Folding",
          "Description": "8-Foot Folding",
          "LanguageId": 57
        },
        "Display": {
          "ProductCategoryId": "xxx",
          "ShowWeb": true,
          "ShowMobile": true,
          "ShowDatavault": true
        },
        "Image": null,
        "Children": [],
        "ProductCategoryId": "xxxx",
        "ParentProductCategoryId": "ABCDE",
        "MenuOrder": 0,
        "ProductCategoryTypeId": 2
      }"Image": null,
        "Children": [],
        "ProductCategoryId": "xxxxxx",
        "ParentProductCategoryId": "12345",
        "MenuOrder": 7,
        "ProductCategoryTypeId": 2
      },
```

So if I start at a top level item, I want to traverse down the children and the children's children to build an XML structure using the Title, ProductCategoryID, and ParentCategoryID.  Ideally I would like to use the Title for the ParentCategoryID (using this a "lookup" for the title) instead of the ProductCategoryID.

How do I use the ParentProductCategoryID to pull the Title from the parent?
Thanks.

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.

Comment: It will be great if you add how your XML should look like.

Comment: And it would be even greater if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, the question is how to do a recursive traverse through the JSON object to pull the object parents Name from the ParentProductCategoryID?

Answer (score 0):

There is how you can traverse this structure recursively

```
public void Traverse(obj)
{
    // your logic with item

    foreach (var childItem in obj.Children)
    {
        Traverse(childItem);
    }
}
```

But if you need more detailed answer, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to traverse the JSON file knowing that for now it will only be three levels deep.  When I come back to refactor, I will create a recursive function to do this.

```
 foreach (ProductCategoryMapItem catMap in cats)
       {
           var xCategory = new XElement(bv + "Category",
               new XElement(bv + "ExternalId", catMap.ProductCategoryId),
               new XElement(bv + "Name", catMap.Description.Title));
           xCategories.Add(xCategory);
           if (catMap.Children.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (ProductCategoryMapItem subcat in catMap.Children)
               {
                   var xSubCategory = new XElement(bv + "Category",
                   new XElement(bv + "ExternalId", subcat.ProductCategoryId),
                   new XElement(bv + "ParentExternalId", subcat.ParentProductCategoryId),
                   new XElement(bv + "Name", subcat.Description.Title));
                   xCategories.Add(xSubCategory);
                   if(subcat.Children.Count > 0 )
                   {
                       foreach(ProductCategoryMapItem subsubcat in subcat.Children)
                       {
                            var xSubSubCategory = new XElement(bv + "Category",
                            new XElement(bv + "ExternalId", subsubcat.ProductCategoryId),
                            new XElement(bv + "ParentExternalId",subsubcat.ParentProductCategoryId),
                            new XElement(bv + "Name", subsubcat.Description.Title));
                            xCategories.Add(xSubSubCategory);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```